# Python library for reading and writing files

Tags: library, python

Is there a Python library for reading/writing to files?

Must have features:

- Python 3 support
- Single line commands for

  - Reading file into a string
  - Reading file into list of string (each line is one string)
  - Writing string to file
  - Writing list of strings to file (each string is a line)

Being able to specify file path relative to script directory would be nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I did not understand completely your question, but the standard python libraries *os*,*path* do what You want.
You can read a file into a string using `read` function:

```
## Read the file and put the content into a string ##
myfilestring = open('myfile','r').read()
```

You can use `readlines` to put the file into a list of string

```
myfileliststring = open('myfile','r').readlines()
```

To write, the same way, You can use *write()* function

```
mystring = "blablablablabla"
fw = open('myfilew','w')
fw.write(mystring)
```

See the complete documentation about [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), to fully understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's already there in builtins.

Depending on what you want to do, it's best to do following.

Iterating over lis of files:

```
for line in open(path, mode):
    ...
```

This is nice because it uses `file` object's iterator facilities that conserve memory (lines are read one by one and discarded by gc when not needed anymore).

Read the whole file:

```
content = open(path, mode).read()
```

(mode is smth like 'rb', or 'read, binary')

For paths, it's another library: `os.path`, also included in base installation. `os.path.realpath` is able to construct actual paths from relative paths IIRC. There's also useful `os.path.abspath`.